# Pivot without aggregate function or Row to Columns by group in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot, aggregate

I am trying to transform rows to columns by type of row.
Here given Table_1 [Table_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3S8PO.jpg)

```
           Table_1
CITY            AMOUNT      TYPE_ID
Moscow         158000          1
New York       94500           1
Moscow         1478000         2
Los Angeles    162000          2
New York       5500000         2
Los Angeles    35400           1
Moscow         741200          1
```

and with select script in result I want to take like in Table_2 [Table_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ug28k.jpg)

```
            Table_2
CITY           TYPE_1_AMOUNT       TYPE_2_AMOUNT
Moscow           158000               1478000
Moscow           741200                  NULL
New York         94500                5500000
Los Angeles      35400                162000
```

I tried with PIVOT. but there must be aggregate func.
Aggregate function MAX() retrieves just max amount...

Comment: Hi, Please replace the images with text. Just put it with commas/tabs as separators and I'll format it later

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select      city
           ,min (case type_id when 1 then amount end)   as type_1_amount
           ,min (case type_id when 2 then amount end)   as type_2_amount

from       (select      city,type_id,amount

                       ,row_number () over 
                        (
                            partition by    city,type_id
                            order by        amount
                        ) as rn

            from        Table_1
            )

group by    city
           ,rn

order by    city
           ,rn
```

---

```
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| CITY        | TYPE_1_AMOUNT | TYPE_2_AMOUNT |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| Los Angeles | 35400         | 162000        |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| Moscow      | 158000        | 1478000       |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| Moscow      | 741200        | (null)        |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
| New York    | 94500         | 5500000       |
+-------------+---------------+---------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

In Oracle 11.1 and higher, you can do the same with the `PIVOT` operator - but first you must distinguish the rows with something like `row_number()` anyway (same as in Dudu's solution). The `PIVOT` solution looks like this:

```
with
     table_1 ( city, amount, type_id ) as (
       select 'Moscow'     ,  158000, 1 from dual union all
       select 'New York'   ,   94500, 1 from dual union all
       select 'Moscow'     , 1478000, 2 from dual union all
       select 'Los Angeles',  162000, 2 from dual union all
       select 'New York'   , 5500000, 2 from dual union all
       select 'Los Angeles',   35400, 1 from dual union all
       select 'Moscow'     ,  741200, 1 from dual
     )
-- end of test data; SQL query begins below this line
select city, type_1, type_2
from   ( select city, amount, type_id,
                row_number() over (partition by city, type_id order by amount) as rn
         from   table_1
       )
pivot  ( min(amount) for type_id in (1 as type_1, 2 as type_2) )
order by city, type_1, type_2    --  ORDER BY is optional
;

CITY            TYPE_1     TYPE_2
----------- ---------- ----------
Los Angeles      35400     162000
Moscow          158000    1478000
Moscow          741200
New York         94500    5500000

4 rows selected.
```